# Maintain hundred of customized branches over master branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Currently we are having one main master branch for our PHP application in shared repository. We have more than 500 clients who are subscribing our software. For different purposes, most of them are having some customization in their project. The customization can from only text field name, up to totally new feature and module, or new table/column in database. 
 
The challenges that we are facing is we maintain hundreds of customized branches and distribute to clients. From  time to time, we provide new feature and update our master branch, then we would like to push master branch changes to customized branch, in order to update customized branch to latest version. 
 
 
Unfortunately this will result in a lot of conflict for customized code vs master code. We need many manpower to go through every single branch and solve all the conflict. This is very inefficiency way and human mistake keep happen when we are solving the conflict.

I am looking for efficiency way to maintain all customized codes in own client's release branch, but they can keep update with master branch when we are releasing new feature, with only minimal effort to merge the coding.

Comment: You poor, poor soul..

Comment: cross post [on programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302147/maintain-hundreds-of-customized-branches-over-master-branch)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a quick and easy answer to this. The fact that there is so much customization allowed in your product basically means you have 500 seperate products.

In my opinion the first step would be to seperate the core product from all the customization. Then create a seperate repository where you keep all your client branches and treat the core product as a dependancy. You could do this by way of a git-submodule or with some sort of dependancy package solution.

This way each client depends on a particular version of your core product, and you can control when a certain client get's upgraded to a newer release.

Of course this means you core product will have to support some form of feature toggles and/or module overrides that allow the customization to take place.